# FTP vs DB - Dynamic Situation

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database, ftp

I have a lot of small pictures to store and these are pictures users can change very often.
The images have an average of **50Kb - 150Kb**. Let's say I have 5000 of these images. Will FTP get unmanageable in the end or will a MsSQL database get to much load giving a normal webpage might use **25** of these images.

What technique should I choose? By the way, in my case im using a hosting solution consisting of a webfarm.

Comment: Put the images on your website, and store the URLs to those images in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at hosting these images on a CDN or similar.  Take what SO use as a good example, [imgur](http://imgur.com/).

I'm thinking the performance and user experience would take you a long time to match.  You might want to store some reference of the images as well.

Of course this may not be an option to you then I'd still put your images on a sub domain of your site, that is setup to deliver static content, again look at [how SO do it](http://sstatic.net/) for an detailed example.